# Best way to reset/revert a docker container to its original image state

Tags: python, docker

I need to be able to restart/revert a container to its original image state. Simply doing a `docker restart` will not work (e.g. files created during a session etc. are still persisted).

Currently I have the following python script that does the work:

```
import subprocess
# Stop and remove a named container if it exists (meaning is running or have exited).
def resetContainer( imageName, containerName ):   
    containerExists=subprocess.check_output(['docker', 'ps','-aqf name=%s' % CONTAINER_NAME])
    if containerExists:
        print('Stop and remove container')
        subprocess.call(['docker', 'stop','%s' % CONTAINER_NAME])
        subprocess.call(['docker', 'rm','%s' % CONTAINER_NAME])
    return;

resetContainer(IMAGE_NAME,CONTAINER_NAME)
# Finally re-create it from image
subprocess.call(['docker', 'run','-d','--name',CONTAINER_NAME,IMAGE_NAME,'tail', '-f','/dev/null'])
```

But is there a better way than this?

I have looked at:
https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html

but from what I can see I will end up with the same number of lines + the additional "overhead" of introducing an additional layer on top of docker "native" commands.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're trying to do.  It looks like you've just written wrapper around `docker rm -f container; docker run -d --name container image_name ...`. I guess you could drop that into a script if you find yourself typing it a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Additional information to [@larsks'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147356/larsks) comment and [OkieOth's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1651840/okieoth) answer:

Containers are considered to be *ephemeral*, so you are already doing the right thing, which is:

1. to `stop` and `remove` the old container
2. to `run` a new one

---

from: [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/)

> ### General guidelines and recommendations
>
> #### Containers should be ephemeral
>
> The container produced by the image your Dockerfile defines should be as ephemeral as possible. **By “ephemeral,” we mean that it can be stopped and destroyed and a new one built and put in place with an absolute minimum of set-up and configuration**.

Answer (score 4):

If you use plain docker or docker-compose, then you need to remove a maybe existing container on your machine and start a new container to get a fresh copy.

```
# stop a container
docker stop CONTAINER_NAME
# removes the container
docker rm -f  CONTAINER_NAME
```

In the case your container uses external volumes (on host or in other containers) you need also to remove them. This could be the case if you work with databases.

I'm using docker stack on my machines. This approach don't need additional dependencies (opposite to docker-compose) and it does a complete container reset for you.

```
# bring up a fresh, clean docker stack
docker stack deploy -c "$composeFile" "$STACK_NAME"

# halt and remove the existing containers
docker stack rm $STACK_NAME
```

Docker stack don't clean mounted host directories.
IMO docker stack has a much cleaner handling of the container state than the pure docker run.